# Mapbox GL - cant set visibility through the zoom function

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a set of markers which I add to my map. Right now, I am using Mapbox GL zoom function to adjust their size based on the zoom level - this works. Now I would like to do something similar with visibility - hide these markers when zoom level is 7 or lower. I used this code to define the layout of the markers:

```
"layout": {
          "icon-image": "marker-{icon}",
          "icon-allow-overlap": true,
          "icon-size": {
              stops: [[6, 0.12], [11, 0.3], [16, 0.3]]
           },
           "icon-offset": [0, -42],
           "visibility": {
              stops: [[7, 'none'], [8, 'visible']]
           }
     }
```

However, this is the error I get in the js console - "*Error: layers.places.layout.visibility: expected one of [visible, none], [object Object] found at Function.module.exports.emitErrors (mapbox-gl.js:149)*"

Needless to say, my markers are not displayed. Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to clarify, you're talking about "icons" (part of a "symbol") layer - not "[markers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker)", which are things added to the map outside the style.

Now, the simple answer here is that the [`visibility`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layout-background-visibility) property doesn't support data-driven styling (note in the table, there's no "data-driven styling" row). Mapbox has indicated they do not intend to implement it, from memory.

Instead, you can use [`icon-opacity`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layout-background-visibility) to achieve almost the same result:

```
"paint": {
    "icon-opacity": {
        stops: [[7, 0], [8, 1]]
    }
}
```

(I say "almost" the same result, because a "visible" but 0-opacity icon is still loaded as the map pans and zooms, so it's slightly worse for performance.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes, setting "icon-opacity" to zero is the approach I used in the end, just wasn´t sure if it´s the optimal way to do it.

Comment: @Steve Bennett, Using the opacity still keeps the ViewAnnoations on the map, which are tied to that particular symbol using `Associated Feature ID`.

Do you have any suggestions on how to manage the visibility of the ViewAnnoations which is tied to a particular Symbol of the Symbol layer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to with ViewAnnotations. You should probably open a new question in any case.